# Generic function that compares sequences

Tags: c++

Write generic function that compares two sequences of same number of elements.Function returns true if all elements are same (a[0]=b[0] , a[1]=b[1] ...) and if are not it returns false.Fucntion takes 3 parameters begin iterators from both sequences and end iterator from first sequnce.
!! Iterators that operate on sequences can be different type !! So here is code that I have done so far but I am getting errors in function why? error : expecter ')' before 'pocetak1'

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;

template <typename S>

bool jednako(vector<S>::const_iterator pocetak1, vector<S>::const_iterator kraj,vector<S>::const_iterator pocetak2){
   for(auto i = pocetak1;i!=kraj;i++){
     if(*pocetak1 != *pocetak2)
         return false
     pocetak1++;
     pocetak2++;
   }
  return true;
}

int main(){
   vector<int> a{0,1,2,3};
   vector<int> b{0,1,2,3};

   cout << jednako<int>(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin());

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's many [algorithmic functions in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), I'm sure one of those should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Though for your specific example, why not just the equivalence operator `==`? As in `a == b`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because sequences dont need to be of same type. One can be vector other can be list or something else.Here I used only vector so it will be easier for me but we are supposed to do it for any sequence

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes u are right ty, but it doesnt get rid of error that i described so I still get |
expected ')' before 'pocetak1'|
 expected ')' before 'kraj'|...

Comment: Huh... You're right, VisualStudio gives a different error, saying you should prefix all those ocurrences of `vector<S>::const_iterator` with `typename`, so try that

Comment: Then how about the generic standard functions? Like [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)?

Comment: And if you really want to write your own functions, use templates for the *iterators* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;

template <typename S>

bool jednako(typename vector<S>::const_iterator pocetak1,typename 
vector<S>::const_iterator kraj,typename vector<S>::const_iterator pocetak2){
   for(auto i = pocetak1;i!=kraj;i++){
       if(*pocetak1 != *pocetak2)
          return false;
       pocetak1++;
       pocetak2++;
       }
  return true;
}

int main(){
   vector<int> a{0,1,2,3};
   vector<int> b{0,1,2,4};

   cout << jednako<int>(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin());

   return 0;
}
```